# How to identify if WebSocket connection limit is reached?

Tags: php, ratchet

I am using "Ratchet Websockets" using PHP for an application with a mobile App on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2. I have been facing an issue with the connection limit. I had faced this a couple of times now. The connection broke sometime and I manually have to restart the `supervisor.conf` and then it works fine. On a busy day, if the connection broke at my night time, it would be a mess. I would like to know if there's any connection limit behind it, if there is, I would like to know how to increase it?

I made some changes in the server settings and updated the file limit.

Here are a few details I been able to get out of my server:

```
sudo sysctl -p
fs.file-max = 2097152

ulimit -n -S
500000

ulimit -n -H
500000
```

I still need to know how to test/verify if the WebSocket connection limit is increased beyond `1024` the default limit. I don't know how to test it.

Please help.

Comment: There are load testing tools available. Maybe something like this might be useful: https://itnext.io/websocket-load-testing-with-artillery-io-b8b7ecbcd7ed. Under the hood Ratchet uses ReactPHP. There are options to use another Event loop. The default is limited to 1024. https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop#loop-implementations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a go.